# Slow UI tests run from Jenkins

Tags: visual-studio-2010, jenkins

I am using Jenkins as my CI build server.  After a build of our software is complete it starts up the automated tests on a slave machine.  The tests that use a web browser run at a very good pace, the tests that run on two different local applications run very slowly.  It takes about 3 seconds between each keystroke.

If I start the tests manually through Visual Studio 2010 on the same slave machine the local application test run just fine (fast keystrokes).

Any idea why the local apps are so slow when run through Jenkins?

Comment: What are you using to test the local apps? Can you log onto the slave with the same user credentials and watch the test in progress? That may give you some clues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same case, but we had similar issues with an automated UI test, and found that we must have a real session open on the slave running the test. NOT RDP.

We did this by using VNC to login to the slave and leave the session open.

I hope this helps.